# How come Ubuntu Cloud Live wont run in a VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

So I'm running the Ubuntu Cloud Live 64bit iso in Virtual Box, just to play around with it and see what it does. I keep running into the problem that as soon as the Ubuntu 12.04 splash screen comes up my entire system (not just the VM) crashes and reboots. It appears nothing has been accomplished when I start up the VM again and it repeats the process.

Is there an explanation for whats causing this issue? Any solution?

Host PC is a 64-bit AMD dual core with 4GB of RAM.
I'm running 12.04 Precise (32-bit) as my host OS with BIOS hardware virtualization enabled.

The VM (running Ubuntu Cloud Live) has 1 GB RAM and a 8GB virtual hard drive.

Comment: Is the fact that I'm running a 64-bit guest OS on a 32-bit host a problem? Although the VirtualBox documentations seems to say it supports it.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't enabled I/O APIC, you should do so - else VirtualBox won't be able to run the 64-bit guest on the 32-bit host.

[From the manual:](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

> On any host, **you should enable the I/O APIC for virtual machines that you intend to use in 64-bit mode.** This is especially true for 64-bit Windows VMs. See the section called “"Advanced" tab”. In addition, for 64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the VM uses the Intel networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver support for the AMD PCNet card; see the section called “Virtual networking hardware”.

Comment: Okay I checked out the manual and played with it. The issue is not the configuration in VirtualBox for 64-bit. And I'm going to check to see if a 32-bit image yields different results.

Comment: The IO APIC is enabled... Still crashing the system.

Comment: @Prof64 posting the logs would help. Can't help without the logs

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know how to access logs on a vm that wont boot. I'll see if I can find the logs on the host when it crashes.

Comment: @Prof64 sorry I meant the logs of VirtualBox and your host system.